# Remove Sidebar for Pages on Canvas Wootheme

Tags: sidebar

In the Canvas WooTheme you can add custom CSS code.

I need some code to hide the sidebar on all pages (or specific pages if possible). But I need to keep it on all posts.

I don't just want it 'blanked out'. I need it to be completely so that the page width isn't limited by the blank space where the sidebar used to be.

Any ideas??

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Most premium theme shops have their own dedicated support forums for premium (purchased) themes. [WooThemes and Canvas are no exception](http://www.woothemes.com/support/). This question is off-topic for this site and should be asked there instead.

Answer (score 2):

Woothemes has 2 option for you ...

- when you add page to choose to hide or show sidebars.
  [image]
- You can also change the page template from default to full width
  [image]